# Segmentation Fault in C using calloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int queensonboard(int n,int m)
{
    int count=0,i,j,flag,x[100];
    char **board;
  /*   board= (char**)calloc(sizeof(char*),n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        board[i]= (char*)calloc(sizeof(char),m);
    }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            scanf("%c",&board[i][j]);
        }
    }*/
   // x==(int*)calloc(sizeof(int),n);
    flag=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        x[i]=0;
    }
    while(i>0)
    {
        while(x[i]<m)
        {
            x[i]++;
           // if(board[i][x[i]]!='#')
         //   {
                for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                {
                    if(x[j]==x[i])
                    {
                        flag=1;
                    }
                    else if(x[j]-x[i]==abs(j-i))
                    {
                        flag=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        flag=0;
                    }
                }
                if(flag==0 && i==n-1)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else if(flag==0)
                {
                    i++;
                }             
           //}
        }
        x[i]=-1;
        i--;
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);

}

int main() {

    int i,n,m,j;
    scanf("%d",&i);
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
        queensonboard(n,m);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code.  The program gives segmentation fault on dynamically allocating any of the arrays x or board.(Commented here.)

That is when i try to allocate with calloc.
Couldnt really figure out why this is happening. Tried changing thins and that but still happening.

Comment: Why are you casting the return value of `calloc`? Why have you commented out the code that is pertinent. `x==(int*)calloc(sizeof(int),n)` is meant to be `x=(int*)calloc(sizeof(int),n)`. Why are you declaring `x` as `int[100]`?

Comment: If `calloc` is returning `NULL`, you should find out why: `if (board == NULL) { perror("could not allocate board"); }`

Comment: Are you sure that n and m are not zero?

Comment: Please show the **exact code** you are executing that has the problem, not code you have modified so that it does not exhibit the problem, and show the **exact input** you are providing to the program.

Comment: @DavidHefferman: I hypothesize the declaration of `x` as `int [100]` is a work-around put in place after `int *x;` with `x==calloc(…);` did not work. So the code in the question is modified in ways that obscure the original problem.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of `calloc` is as follows:

```
void *calloc(size_t num, size_t size);
```

> **num**  Number of elements to allocate.
>   **size** Size of each element.

You have your arguments swapped.  It should be like this:

```
board = calloc(n, sizeof(char *));
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    board[i]= calloc(m, sizeof(char));
}
```

Also, this line is incorrect:

```
x == (int*)calloc(sizeof(int), n);
```

This, is comparing the address of `x` to the address that `calloc` returns. The logic is incorrect too.  The way you have `x` defined, it is an array of 100 `int`s.

If you want an array of `int` pointers, you need to do this:

```
int *x[100];
```

If you want a pointer to array of 100 `int`s, you need to do this:

```
int (*x)[100];
```

If you're simply trying to allocate memory for `x`, you've already accomplished that with your declaration:

```
int x[100];
```

Comment: Multiplication is commutative

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Alignment is not. That might not be the cause of the OP’s problem, but `calloc` should be used with the arguments in the correct order.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Alignment is important, but my understanding is that calloc (and malloc) return pointers with alignment suitable for all objects.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: C 2011 changed the specification of the allocation routines say that they return a pointer suitably aligned for an object of a fundamental alignment. If an implementation supports extended alignments, then passing `calloc` the parameters in the incorrect order could result in it not knowing you are allocated objects with an extended alignment. E.g., an implementation could support a SIMD vector type of 16 bytes or a memory page allocation of 4096 bytes, and `calloc(16, 3)` or `calloc(4096, 3)` would not provide the required alignment for those.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Obviously, that is not the problem here, but is it really necessary to provide a defense for using a routine in the way it is documented and not using completely unnecessary changes?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I totally agree that you must pass the params in the right order. My rather terse comment was meant to suggest that the problem lay elsewhere.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I don't think that the standard supports your claim. The only thing that is said there that the allocation functions fulfill fundamental alignment requirements, not more and not less. Nothing specifies that `calloc` will return a different alignment if the `size` argument is larger. Actually `calloc` can't know if the larger size results in a larger alignment requirement. C11 provides `aligned_alloc` for such special situations.

Comment: @JensGustedt It's basically just a blob of memory without alignment.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Implementations can provide these features. Use `calloc` the way it is documented. It is not true that `calloc` cannot know if a larger size results in a larger alignment requirement; an implementation is permitted to choose to have `calloc` return more strictly aligned pointers for larger alignments. The standard does not **require** this, but it is **permitted**. So to write good code, use `calloc` the way it is documented.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Furthermore, even if an object does not require a certain alignment, it may benefit from it, for performance. Thus, `calloc(8, 4)` might allocate space that **works** for four eight-byte doubles, but `calloc(4, 8)` could allocate space that is **optimal** for four eight-byte doubles.

Comment: Are you talking about packing?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, extended aligment properties reliably and portably are provided by `aligned_alloc` and not much else. But don't get me wrong, I don't say that one shouldn't use the arguments to `calloc` corresponding to their naming. But this is more a question of coding style than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious explanation for a segmentation fault is that you are de-referencing an invalid pointer. The obvious way for that to happen would be for any of the calls to `calloc` to return `NULL`. And `calloc` does that when it fails. You are not checking the return value of `calloc` for errors and I think it very likely that one of the calls returns `NULL` because you supplied invalid parameters.

So, debug the problem by checking the return value of the calls to `calloc`, and checking the input parameters that you pass. I know it's frustrating to have to do this, but you must check for errors in all user input, and you must check the return values of all calls to memory allocation functions.

---

This line

```
x==(int*)calloc(sizeof(int),n)
```

where you perform comparison rather than assignment is also clearly problematic. You meant:

```
int *x = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

---

And yes, you have the arguments to `calloc` swapped as others point out. You should certainly fix that but I do not believe that to be the cause of your problem.